# Interaction between Torment of Hailfire and Persist

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I choose a creature with persist for one repetition of [Torment of Hailfire](https://scryfall.com/card/hou/77/torment-of-hailfire), will it return to play before the next repetition to choose it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not.

Persist in a triggered ability:

> 702.78a Persist is a triggered ability. “Persist” means “When this permanent is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, if it had no -1/-1 counters on it, return it to the battlefield under its owner’s control with a -1/-1 counter on it.”

Triggered abilities trigger while other spells and abilities resolve, bit they aren't put on the stack until afterwards, and they don't resolve until a little while after that.

The only (common) thing that can really intervene in a case like this is a so-called *replacement effect* (those usually contain the word "instead"). And while there may be replacement effects that can let you get out of the Torment predicament cheaper, I can't think of one right now.